# React Native Conditional Rendering not working, help needed

Tags: react-native

In my RN app I try to render the Drawer menu content depending on the authentication state. My code however returns:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MenuContent
```

I am fairly happy with the code structure, so I wouldn't change that, but I don't know how to fix the syntax.

Here's my code:

```
class DrawerContent extends Component {

  AuthorizedMenuContent = (props) => () => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text> Authorized </Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  UnAuthorizedMenuContent = (props) => () => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text> NOT Authorized </Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  MenuContent = (props) => () => {
    const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return <AuthorizedMenuContent />;
    }
    return <UnAuthorizedMenuContent />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MenuContent isLoggedIn={false}/>      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the empty parenthesis `MenuContent = (props) => { }` and not `MenuContent = (props) => ()  => { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MenuContent, AuthorizedMenuContent and UnAuthorizedMenuContent are functions, not components, you have to call them this way :

```
{this.MenuContent(false)}
```

The declaration of your functions is not good, you have to replace

```
MenuContent = (props) => () => {
```

by

```
MenuContent = (props) => {
```

I created a working example on stack https://snack.expo.io/@sanjar/so-53390970

Comment: I made the changes. Now the code runs, but the result is an empty menu.

Comment: I checked your comment and modified my answer with a link to a working example, please tell me if you have any questions

Comment: It works beautifully now. Exactly how I imagined to set this up! Thank you!